# I need to make Person cards line up in a slider that can be browsed after going through the array with map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider

I have a component PersonList, which has a component Person, the component Person contains a template of one card, the data in the component Person come from an array of data in the component Person, then in the component PersonList I bypass the entire array of data through map() in order to display not one but the entire array of data in different cards, Now the question, I need after all the cards appeared, they were not displayed on the page statically, and lined up, with a width of 3 cards and the user can list them using two buttons (forward, backward) how do I do it?
All of the component code below

```
import Person from '../person/Person';
import './personList.css';
import {personArr} from '../helpers/personList';

const PersonList = () => {
  return (
    <div className="list_wrapper">
      {personArr.map((el, i) => {
        return <Person key={i} name={el.name} post={el.post} img={el.img} exp={el.exp} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default PersonList;
```

The persona component looks like this

```
 const Person = ({name, exp, post, img}) => {
  return (
    <div className="person_wrapper">
      <div className="person_img">
        <img src={img} alt={name} />
      </div>
      <div className="person_text">
        <h2 className="person_name"> {name} </h2>
        <p className="person_post"> {post} </p>
        <p className="person_exp"> {exp} </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Person;
```

personList array

```
 const personArr = [
  {
    img: 'sdfs',
    name: 'Колмыков Александр Михайлович',
    post: 'Анастазиолог-реаниматолог',
    exp: 'Стаж работы на скорой 24 года',
  },
  {
    img: 'sdf',
    name: 'Колмыков Александр Михайлович',
    post: 'Анастазиолог-реаниматолог',
    exp: 'Стаж работы на скорой 24 года',
  },
  {
    img: 'sgds',
    name: 'Колмыков Александр Михайлович',
    post: 'Анастазиолог-реаниматолог',
    exp: 'Стаж работы на скорой 24 года',
  },
  {
    img: 'fdhdf',
    name: 'Колмыков Александр Михайлович',
    post: 'Анастазиолог-реаниматолог',
    exp: 'Стаж работы на скорой 24 года',
  },
];

export {personArr};
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to figure out how to paginate your PersonList component.

When implementing pagination, we need to keep track of few variable `pageSize`, `page`, `array position`.

In the example below, were are slicing the array of people to view only portion of the array at a time. You can think of each slice as a `page`. `Page size` is constant because we don't have a requirement to make it variable, however, if we wanted the user to be able to choose their own list size, we would manage that with `state`. Lastly, `page` is the only variable in this example that needs to be managed by state, because a user can dynamically change that using the `Forward`, and `Backward` buttons.

```
const PersonList = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const pageSize = 3;

  return (
    <div className="list_wrapper">
      {personArr.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, pageSize * page).map((el, i) => {
        return (
          <Person
            key={i}
            name={el.name}
            post={el.post}
            img={el.img}
            exp={el.exp}
          />
        );
      })}
      <button disabled={page <= 1} onClick={() => setPage((prev) => prev - 1)}>
        Backward
      </button>
      <button
        disabled={personArr.length / pageSize <= page}
        onClick={() => setPage((prev) => prev + 1)}
      >
        Forward
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PersonList;
```

Here is demo of my attempt at resolving your issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-silence-l4r1qy?file=/src/App.js